# I can't print some characters due to encoding (I guess), using C

Tags: c, encoding, utf-8, fread

I have to read a txt file (using pure C language) that have some characters like "ã, é, í, ç, ê" and I cant.
Already tried to use  setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); My pc locale is portuguese_brazil.1252 so it was suppose to work.
When I use the setlocale and then I do printf("á, ã, ê, ç"); it works, but what I have to print comes from a txt file (utf-8 encoded). I guess that the "fread" is not getting the characters correctly... What should I do. Sorry if the question is bad asked, i'ts my first one, and my english isn't perfect.

I'm using Windows and Codeblocks.
I tried to use "pt_BR.utf8" "pt_BR.utf-8" and other stuff I found online.. I really thing the error is in the fread. How can I tell the fread to convert the UTF8 to my output?

Comment: which toolchain are you using?

Comment: `""` is the C locale. To print UTF-8 you will need to set a UTF-8 locale. The actual locale strings are implementation-defined so check your compiler's documentation.

Comment: Without further instructions, `fread` will not automatically convert from UTF8 (your input) to your local codepage (your output). You need to tell it to. Is this under Windows, and a console program? (Which your details seem to suggest.)

Comment: I'm using Windows and Codeblocks. Don't know how to look in the compiler documentation for that, and also don't know what toolchain I'm using.. I don't know much programming yet..

Comment: I tried to use "pt_BR.utf8" "pt_BR.utf-8" and other stuff I found online.. I really thing the error is in the fread. How can I tell the fread to convert the UTF8 to my output?

Comment: Your locale almost never matters. Your code can and should just deal with the UTF-8 much the same as it deals with ascii, except remember that a "character" can be more than one byte.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean that `fread` should be changed. After reading a UTF8 string you need to convert it to your output locale. There may be some Windows API function for that.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I'm under the illusion that the C locale is called `"C"` and that the name `""` is the default locale based on environment settings, which may or may not be the same as the C locale.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sounds right